# What could be a cause for getdents returning different results on 2 systems?

Tags: system-calls

I have a weird situation that on one server I am getting following results:

```
vagrant@shopping:/vagrant/deployer-example$ uname -a
Linux shopping 4.19.0-0.bpo.9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.118-2+deb10u1~bpo9+1 (2020-06-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux


 vagrant@shopping:/vagrant/deployer-example$ bin/php --version
PHP 8.0.3 (cli) (built: Mar  5 2021 08:36:11) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.3, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.3, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
vagrant@shopping:/vagrant/deployer-example$ sudo ldd --version
ldd (Debian GLIBC 2.24-11+deb9u4) 2.24
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
vagrant@shopping:/vagrant/deployer-example$ php -r 'var_dump(glob("/vagrant/deployer-example/config/{routes}/*.yaml", GLOB_BRACE));'
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(56) "/vagrant/deployer-example/config/routes/annotations.yaml"
  [1]=>
  string(55) "/vagrant/deployer-example/config/routes/easy_admin.yaml"
  [2]=>
  string(52) "/vagrant/deployer-example/config/routes/monitor.yaml"
  [3]=>
  string(59) "/vagrant/deployer-example/config/routes/nelmio_api_doc.yaml"
}
vagrant@shopping:/vagrant/deployer-example$ php -r 'var_dump(glob("/vagrant/deployer-example/config/{routes}/*.yaml/", GLOB_BRACE));'
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(56) "/vagrant/deployer-example/config/routes/annotations.yaml"
  [1]=>
  string(55) "/vagrant/deployer-example/config/routes/easy_admin.yaml"
  [2]=>
  string(52) "/vagrant/deployer-example/config/routes/monitor.yaml"
  [3]=>
  string(59) "/vagrant/deployer-example/config/routes/nelmio_api_doc.yaml"
}
```

But on second system

```
deployer-example@s2-stg-s01:~/deployer/current$ uname -a
Linux s2-stg-s01 4.19.0-0.bpo.9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.118-2+deb10u1~bpo9+1 (2020-06-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux
deployer-example@s2-stg-s01:~/deployer/current$ bin/php --version
PHP 8.0.3 (cli) (built: Mar  5 2021 08:36:11) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.3, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.3, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
deployer-example@s2-stg-s01:~/deployer/current$ ldd --version
ldd (Debian GLIBC 2.24-11+deb9u4) 2.24
Copyright © 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Dies ist freie Software; in den Quellen befinden sich die Lizenzbedingungen.
Es gibt KEINERLEI Garantie; nicht einmal für die TAUGLICHKEIT oder
VERWENDBARKEIT FÜR EINEN ANGEGEBENEN ZWECK.
Implementiert von Roland McGrath und Ulrich Drepper.
deployer-example@s2-stg-s01:~/deployer/current$ php -r 'var_dump(glob("/home/deployer-example/deployer/releases/437/config/{routes}/*.yaml", GLOB_BRACE));'
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(75) "/home/deployer-example/deployer/releases/437/config/routes/annotations.yaml"
  [1]=>
  string(74) "/home/deployer-example/deployer/releases/437/config/routes/easy_admin.yaml"
  [2]=>
  string(71) "/home/deployer-example/deployer/releases/437/config/routes/monitor.yaml"
  [3]=>
  string(78) "/home/deployer-example/deployer/releases/437/config/routes/nelmio_api_doc.yaml"
}
deployer-example@s2-stg-s01:~/deployer/current$ php -r 'var_dump(glob("/home/deployer-example/deployer/releases/437/config/{routes}/*.yaml/", GLOB_BRACE));'
array(0) {
}
```

I was debugging it with strace and found that for first system it reports:

```
open("/vagrant/deployer-example/config/routes", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_dev=makedev(0, 44), st_ino=86530891, st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=8, st_size=224, st_atime=2021-03-12T15:24:14+0000, st_mtime=2021-03-12T15:19:23+0000, st_ctime=2021-03-12T15:19:23+0000}) = 0
brk(0x562b5bb63000)                     = 0x562b5bb63000
getdents(3, [{d_ino=1031795, d_off=1, d_reclen=24, d_name=".", d_type=DT_UNKNOWN}, {d_ino=1031796, d_off=2, d_reclen=24, d_name="..", d_type=DT_UNKNOWN}, {d_ino=1031797, d_off=3, d_reclen=40, d_name="annotations.yaml", d_type=DT_UNKNOWN}, {d_ino=1031798, d_off=4, d_reclen=24, d_name="dev", d_type=DT_UNKNOWN}, {d_ino=1031799, d_off=5, d_reclen=40, d_name="easy_admin.yaml", d_type=DT_UNKNOWN}, {d_ino=1031800, d_off=6, d_reclen=32, d_name="monitor.yaml", d_type=DT_UNKNOWN}, {d_ino=1031801, d_off=7, d_reclen=40, d_name="nelmio_api_doc.yaml", d_type=DT_UNKNOWN}], 32768) = 224
newfstatat(3, "annotations.yaml", {st_dev=makedev(0, 44), st_ino=87279600, st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=8, st_size=135, st_atime=2021-03-12T15:19:24+0000, st_mtime=2021-03-12T15:19:23+0000, st_ctime=2021-03-12T15:19:23+0000}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(3, "easy_admin.yaml", {st_dev=makedev(0, 44), st_ino=87279603, st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=8, st_size=127, st_atime=2021-03-05T16:00:41+0000, st_mtime=2021-03-05T16:00:41+0000, st_ctime=2021-03-05T16:00:41+0000}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(3, "monitor.yaml", {st_dev=makedev(0, 44), st_ino=87279604, st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=8, st_size=137, st_atime=2021-03-05T16:00:41+0000, st_mtime=2021-03-05T16:00:41+0000, st_ctime=2021-03-05T16:00:41+0000}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(3, "nelmio_api_doc.yaml", {st_dev=makedev(0, 44), st_ino=87279605, st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=8, st_size=367, st_atime=2021-03-05T16:00:41+0000, st_mtime=2021-03-05T16:00:41+0000, st_ctime=2021-03-05T16:00:41+0000}, 0) = 0
getdents(3, [], 32768)                  = 0
close(3)                                = 0
```

but for second one

```
open("/home/deployer-example/deployer/releases/437/config/routes", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
fstat(5, {st_dev=makedev(8, 17), st_ino=123601048, st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_nlink=3, st_uid=1084, st_gid=1084, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=8, st_size=4096, st_atime=2021-03-12T16:18:27+0100.512902323, st_mtime=2021-03-12T16:17:55+0100.984164843, st_ctime=2021-03-12T16:17:55+0100.984164843}) = 0
brk(0x557145c2a000)                     = 0x557145c2a000
getdents(5, [{d_ino=123601055, d_off=2396884471359371616, d_reclen=40, d_name="nelmio_api_doc.yaml", d_type=DT_REG}, {d_ino=123601053, d_off=2713394375622026215, d_reclen=32, d_name="monitor.yaml", d_type=DT_REG}, {d_ino=123601049, d_off=3087430337415459848, d_reclen=40, d_name="easy_admin.yaml", d_type=DT_REG}, {d_ino=123601050, d_off=7440370618885146051, d_reclen=24, d_name="dev", d_type=DT_DIR}, {d_ino=123600993, d_off=8681975314043990400, d_reclen=24, d_name="..", d_type=DT_DIR}, {d_ino=123601479, d_off=9220757504948275036, d_reclen=40, d_name="annotations.yaml", d_type=DT_REG}, {d_ino=123601048, d_off=9223372036854775807, d_reclen=24, d_name=".", d_type=DT_DIR}], 32768) = 224
getdents(5, [], 32768)                  = 0
close(5)                                = 0
```

Both systems are running under same Debian version, under EXT4 filesystem and are provisioned with same Ansible scripts, so should also have same core packages.

How can I narrow this down to the culprit? What possible reasons there could be why these two servers behave differently?

Comment: Both straces show `getdents()` behaving exactly the same, returning 7 entries with a total size of 224. I guess you're mainly concerned about the PHP `glob()` function behaving differently. There's a slight difference in the PHP versions used, perhaps some PHP configuration variables might be different as well.

Comment: `glob("*/")` returning things that don't end in `/` looks like a bug in that `glob()` to me.

Comment: But bug in where? I want to patch this so systems behave same and people don't run into this issue on production again when it's working in VM fine.

Comment: Looks like the PHP 8.0.2 on the first server is misbehaving by returning stuff that should not be there. Perhaps you should start by making sure you are using the same PHP version in both testing and production.

Comment: Done upgraded both to PHP 8.0.3, but same result.

Comment: Those `DT_UNKNOWN` and `st_nlink=1` on the directory suggest the first one is not ext4. Can you confirm with `df -T /vagrant/deployer-example/config/routes` for instance?

Comment: Indeed, looks like you are right

`vagrant@shopping:/vagrant/deployer-example$ df -T /vagrant/deployer-example/config/routes
Filesystem     Type   1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
vagrant        prl_fs 488245288 426727712  61517576  88% /vagrant`. So Parallels bug perhaps that it works with `/` at the end.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed that the `glob()` in PHP is just a thin wrapper around the same function in libc. The implementation in glibc is what is getting confused by the first system.

Comment: But glibc version is included in my post and according that output it's same on both systems :/

Comment: I can reproduce a similar bug in that `php -r 'var_dump(glob("./*/"));'` (but not `php -r 'var_dump(glob("*/"));'` !?) returns broken symlinks. I can reproduce your problem on a fs formatted as a minix fs as well (where directories don't store file types either and `d_type` is DT_UNKNOWN)

Comment: Just to get this correctly (I'm not much of a systems programmer or kernel guru), glob() bug is in glibc so we should probably report this bug there?

Comment: Yeah, even though both systems use the same libc, the first system triggers a corner case (weird filesystem that does not return entry type in getdents data) in the glibc code. The second system just does what 99% filesystems do today and returns the data immediately, triggering a more efficient code path (and one that is the most tested nowadays).

Comment: Yes, it seems to be in glibc, so we'd need to check the doc to see if it's not expected behaviour, and on the latest version to see if it hasn't been fixed already.

Comment: I can reproduce with glibc 2.33. I see the code turns on the `GLOB_ONLYDIR` (GNU specific) flag when the pattern ends in `/` and the documentation for that flag says: *If the information about the type of the file is easily
     available non-directories will be rejected but no extra work will
     be done to determine the information for each file.  I.e., the
     caller must still be able to filter directories out*. Still, I'd call it a bug as it breaks POSIX compliance (and you can see `glob()` still does a `stat()` on each of those files so it has the information).

Comment: That's very cool that this issue took so much of your interest and you went extra mile to confirm this is still present in last glibc version :) Could you then also create bug report issue for glibc (and link it here)? As it seem, you are much more capable of writing the correct description of issue than me!

Comment: Oh actually after checking glibc tracker, looks like somebody reported this bug yesterday already: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=25659  If that was you, much thanks!

Comment: No, wasn't me, but you can see [that guy had already added a workaround for that glibc bug to GNU `make` a few years back](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/commit/?id=b7acb10e86dc8f5fdf2a2bbd87e1059c315e31d6) so had probably looked into that issue back then and was reminded of it from this discussion.

Comment: Wow. Actually, he reported it almost exactly a year ago. And also used "minix" FS as a filesystem example that doesn't supply `d_type`. What are the odds of that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As could be seen thanks to verbose mode in strace enabled (`-v`), these getdents calls were returning `d_type=DT_REG` on first system, but on second one `d_type=DT_UNKNOWN`. Reason for this is that while in first case filesystem used is `ext4`, in second case it is `prl_fs`. `prl_fs` filesystem itself apparently doesn't return known `d_type`.

This triggers an edge case in glob() function in glibc. There was a glibc bug issue reported for this at https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=25659

I've also contacted Parallels support where I ask them to stop returning DT_UNKNOWN as a d_type. Since Parallels 16.5.0-49183, they fixed this :)

Comment: Note that the type of a file is something that belongs with the file. Some filesystems (most these days) also duplicate that information in the entries of all directories the file is linked to (for performance improvement purposes) but don't have to. I'd expect that `prl_fs` is some sort of "network" file system between guest and host. If the host OS doesn't make that information readily available without extra effort, it would be reasonable for the `prl_fs` implementation not to include it in the directory entries. That would be a perfectly valid thing to do.